# How to make a table row editable to update the value in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm trying to build an Angular application that takes data from an excel sheet and displays it in a table on upload. I have added an `edit` link under one column for editing the row data, upon clicking edit it shows `save` and `cancel` buttons. I tried to implement this functionality with some components but it didn't work out as I expected.
Can someone suggest to me a way to implement this, please?

-> app.component.html

```html
<div>
  <h3>Upload Excel File</h3>
  <div class="row">
      <input type="file" (change)="uploadFile($event)" placeholder="Choose File" accept=".xls,.xlsx,.ods">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" (click)="upload()" >Upload</button>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div>
  <table *ngIf="submitted">
    <tr>
      <th *ngFor = "let column of tableHeaders">
          {{column}}
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor = "let row of excelData; let i=index">
        <td >
            {{row["Employee Name"]}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{row["Email Id"]}}
        </td>
        <td>
          {{row["UID"]}}
        </td>
        <td>
          {{row["place"]}}
        </td>
        <td>
          {{row["DOB"]}}
        </td>
        <td>
          <button *ngIf="enableEdit && enableEditIndex == i" (click)="enableEdit=false" class="btn page-secondary-action-btn" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>

          <button *ngIf="enableEdit && enableEditIndex == i" id="saveBtn" class="btn page-primary-action-btn" (click)="saveSegment()" type="submit">Save</button>
          
          <a href="#" class="table-row-action edit-action" *ngIf="!enableEdit" (click)="editRowData($event, i)">Edit</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

-> app.component.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'excelUpload';
  buffer: any;
  file: File;
  worksheet: any;
  excelData: any[];
  excelDatas: any[];
  tableData: any[];
  uploadFile(event) {
    this.file = event.target.files[0];
  }
  private dataLoaded: boolean;
  submitted: boolean = false;
  tableHeaders = ["Employee Name", "Email Id", "place", "UID", "DOB", "Actions"]; 
  tableRows = [];
  enableEdit: boolean = false;
  enableEditIndex = null;

  upload() {
    this.submitted = true;
    let fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = (e) => {
      this.buffer = fileReader.result;
      var data = new Uint8Array(this.buffer);
      var arr = new Array();
      for (var i = 0; i != data.length; ++i) {
        arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(data[i]);
      }
      var bstr = arr.join("");
      var workbook = XLSX.read(bstr, { type: "binary" });
      var first_sheet_name = workbook.SheetNames[0];
      var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[first_sheet_name]; // worksheet_name
      this.excelData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet, { raw: true })
      this.excelDatas = this.excelData.map(data => Object.values(data));
      console.log(this.excelData);
      // console.log(this.excelData[0]["Email Id"]);
      // var newArr = this.excelData.map((data, index) => {
      //   console.log(data)
      // })
    }
    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(this.file);
  }

  editRowData(e, i) {
    this.enableEdit = true;
    this.enableEditIndex = i;
  }

  saveSegment(){}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix my issue with `NG-ZORRO` components. NG-ZORRO table components have an `Editable Cells` component with which I was able to edit each row inside the tables.

Reference:
[Click here for reference](https://ng.ant.design/components/table/en#components-table-demo-edit-cell)

=> app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'edit-table';
  i = 0;
  editId: string | null = null;
  listOfData: any;
  file: File;
  buffer: any;
  worksheet: any;
  excelData: any[];
  tableData: any;
  uploadFile(event) {
    this.file = event.target.files[0];
  }
  submitted: boolean = false;
  
  // function to read data from excel
  upload() {
    this.submitted = true;
    let fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = (e) => {
      this.buffer = fileReader.result;
      var data = new Uint8Array(this.buffer);
      var arr = new Array();
      for (var i = 0; i != data.length; ++i) {
        arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(data[i]);
      }
      var bstr = arr.join("");
      var workbook = XLSX.read(bstr, { type: "binary" });
      var first_sheet_name = workbook.SheetNames[0];
      var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[first_sheet_name]; // worksheet_name
      this.excelData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet, { raw: true })
      // this.tableData = this.excelData.map(data => Object.values(data)); 
    }
    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(this.file);
  }

  startEdit(id: string): void {
    this.editId = id;
  }

  stopEdit(): void {
    this.editId = null;
  }

  addRow(): void {
    this.tableData = [   
    ];
    this.i++;
  }

  deleteRow(id: string): void {
    this.tableData = this.tableData.filter(d => d.id !== id);
  }
}
```

=> app.component.html

```
<div>
  <h3>Upload Excel File</h3>
  <div class="row">
      <input type="file" (change)="uploadFile($event)" placeholder="Choose File" accept=".xls,.xlsx,.ods">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" (click)="upload()" >Upload</button>
  </div>
</div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <nz-table #editRowTable nzBordered [nzData]="excelData" *ngIf="submitted">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Employee Name</th>
          <th>Email Id</th>
          <th>UID</th>
          <th>place</th>
          <th>DOB</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let data of editRowTable.data" class="editable-row">

          <td>
            <div class="editable-cell" [hidden]="editId === data.id" (click)="startEdit(data.id)">
              {{ data['Employee Name'] }}
            </div>
            <input [hidden]="editId !== data.id" type="text" nz-input [(ngModel)]="data['Employee Name']" (blur)="stopEdit()" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="editable-cell" [hidden]="editId === data.id" (click)="startEdit(data.id)">
              {{ data['Email Id']}}
            </div>
            <input [hidden]="editId !== data.id" type="text" nz-input [(ngModel)]="data['Email Id']" (blur)="stopEdit()" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="editable-cell" [hidden]="editId === data.id" (click)="startEdit(data.id)">
              {{ data['UID']}}
            </div>
            <input [hidden]="editId !== data.id" type="text" nz-input [(ngModel)]="data['UID']" (blur)="stopEdit()" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="editable-cell" [hidden]="editId === data.id" (click)="startEdit(data.id)">
              {{ data['Place'] }}
            </div>
            <input [hidden]="editId !== data.id" type="text" nz-input [(ngModel)]="data['Place']" (blur)="stopEdit()" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="editable-cell" [hidden]="editId === data.id" (click)="startEdit(data.id)">
              {{ data['DOB'] }}
            </div>
            <input [hidden]="editId !== data.id" type="text" nz-input [(ngModel)]="data['DOB']" (blur)="stopEdit()" />
          </td>
          
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </nz-table>
```